# Does Microsoft recommend method or query syntax?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

Does Microsoft Net Core 3 recommend method syntax or query syntax for Linq Entity Framework queries? This is a debate in our workplace, we are curious.

This is not Opinion based question, but fact, since I am looking for Microsoft recommendation, not people opinion . Thanks

Comment: Query syntax is C# language feature and as such has nothing to do with frameworks.

Comment: This isn't an opinion based question, guys. Microsoft can either objectively recommend one, both or none. What's the subjectivity here? Enough with this power play. Ughh.

Comment: In late 2022, [Microsoft's Language Integrated Query (LINQ) (C#) page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/#query-expression-overview) says, "As a rule when you write LINQ queries, we recommend that you use query syntax whenever possible and method syntax whenever necessary."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to recommend either. They're equivalent, in that query expressions are effectively "preprocessed" to method syntax.

I view it as very worthwhile to know both:

- Queries with joins, grouping etc tend to be more readable with query expressions due to the transparent identifiers introduced by the compiler
- Many queries either can't be represented in query expressions, or are simpler to read with method syntax

Learn both thoroughly, and use whichever is most appropriate for any given scenario.

Comment: Some additions to your points: 1) `let` doesn't exist in method syntax and can be a handy shortcut when writing code. 2) some constructs don't exist in query syntax (like `SelectMany()`), and combining query with method looks ugly. 3) method syntax is easier to compose because query components contain their own lambda argument declarations so they can be independently moved around without worrying about dependency to a previously declared query argument.

Comment: thanks the question really is, what is Microsoft official per recommendation?

Comment: @AlexRodgers: There *is* no official recommendation for precisely the reasons I've given. It's like asking whether there's a recommendation to use `string` or `int` - you use whichever is most appropriate for your situation; in this case it's what leads to the most readable code.